# Images disappear in Rails app using ActiveStorage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, rails-activestorage

I'm encountering a very weird bug in my Rails app.
I'm using ActiveStorage to store images on S3 and images sometimes appear but sometimes don't.

If you scroll down a little bit, one card ("Yoga retreat") doesn't have a thumbnail.

My code:

```
<a href="#" style="background-image: url('<%= rails_representation_path(experience.thumbnail) %>')">
```

experience.rb

```
def thumbnail
  self.cover.variant(resize: "300x300").processed
end
```

What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE**

When I deploy the problem goes away (I can see the image), even if the changes have nothing to do with the image.
If I then add another card, the image doesn't appear again, unless I deploy again.

**UPDATE 2**
I've found out the problem but I don't know how to fix it. The problem is the cache. It has nothing to do with ActiveStorage. The image is not displayed because it points to the old url. In fact, if I clear the cache, everything works.

In my view I use collection fragment caching

```
<%= render partial: :experience, collection: @experiences, cached: true %>
```

Why does it not update when I update my record?
I've noticed it doesnt't just not update my image, it doesn't update my title too if I change it.

Comment: Sorry to digress but is the card layout taken from a library or its built inhouse?

Comment: I also found this bug. only when I cache the result of rails_representation_path in view.

Comment: Nice website, i've always wanted to make a website like that on rails

Answer (score 0):

First off, awesome app!

Second, you have to check out your terminal. ActiveStorage doesn't delete its previous state, which means, if you add another image to an existing image, there will be an error, because the storage wasn't null. I think that your 'yoga' picture is somehow connected in the code to any further uploads, or that you use active_storage the wrong way.

My suggestion is to run

```
attachment.purge_later()
```

before you attach the image (inside your controller). Also, are you using turbolinks? Make sure to use

`$(document).on(turbolinks:load, function(){})`

before you run all your javascript.

If that didn't helped, post your controller that handles the upload, your storage place and the configuration (make sure to NOT post your credentials!).

Also, what host are you using? Try to go into the rails console when the image disappears and get the id of the 'yoga' image and see if it becomes null.

Last thing: i could see the image when i visited your site.

Greetings!

Comment: Hi, the records are all created from the admin dashboard (I use activeadmin gem), so no controller to upload the image. As for the credentials, this is what I have amazon:
  service: S3
  access_key_id: <%= Rails.application.credentials.aws[:access_key_id] %>
  secret_access_key: <%= Rails.application.credentials.aws[:secret_access_key] %>
  region: <%= Rails.application.credentials.aws[:region] %>
  bucket: <%= Rails.application.credentials.aws[:bucket] %>

Comment: Would you like to add an image, so that the image disappears (like you descrbied in the OP) and than go into your rails console and check if the image is null for the specific post? This would likely tell us a lot.

Comment: I just found out that the image is not displayed only when the image is changed. So, if I create a new record, the image is displayed fine. But if I replace the image with another one, the new one is not displayed. Even more weird is that if I purge the image from the console and then I upload a new image, the new image is still not displayed. I'm lost :)

Comment: yes, this behaviour is probably due the active storage purge issue. Are you able to edit other images, or does this occur with every image you try to update/edit? Also, when you purge an image, is the attachement then afterwards nil? You must make sure to run purge before you attach another image, otherwise you'll gonna delete the new uploaded one. I suggest you to create a simple project with one model who has one attachment and then use the exact same setup with sw3 and your current host. Other than that, you could try to use carrierwave gem, its easy to setup and works fine.